# Writing an XSLT to pull certain attributes out of XML file

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

This would be my first attempt at writing an XSLT that actually does something signigicant and that helps me in my work.  I have written xpath xpression's before and have gotten pretty good with them, just need to get my feet wet with XSLT's to really start cooking.  Anywho,

I have an XML file that has certain nodes in it with `value` attributes.  I want to get all nodes with `name` attributes to print out their `value` attributes in a text file...

Here is what I have so far... Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataTemplateSpecification>
<templates>
<template>
  <elements>
    <element id="element0" name="PatientId" display="Patient ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="false" value="207">
      <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/PATIENT_ID" />
      <validation>
        <rules>
          <rule id="r0" test="#element0.value == ''">
            <fail>
              <html>
                <b>Patient ID is null, value must be present</b>
              </html>
            </fail>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </validation>
    </element>
    <element id="element1" name="EncounterId" display="Encounter ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="false" value="144">
      <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/FOCUSED_READMISSIONS_ID" />
      <validation>
        <rules>
          <rule id="r0" test="#element0.value == ''">
            <fail>
              <html>
                <b>Patient ID is null, value must be present</b>
              </html>
            </fail>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </validation>
    </element>
    </template></template></dataTemplateSpecification>
```

Here is the very basic XSLT that I have written...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="//dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template/elements/element[@name=*]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@value"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I will keep cracking at this, and if you guys could help at all I would be eternally grateful.  I of course will post a solution for any one that reads this and is also intrigued by this question should I discover the solution on my own.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is probably one of the simplest and shortest complete transformations that performs the requested processing**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="element[@name and @value]">
     <element>
       <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat(@name, ': ', @value)"/>
     </element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML** (corrected several times to be made wellformed):

```
<dataTemplateSpecification>
    <templates>
        <template>
            <elements>
                <element id="element0" name="PatientId" display="Patient ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="false" value="207">
                    <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/PATIENT_ID" />
                    <validation>
                        <rules>
                            <rule id="r0" test="#element0.value == ''">
                                <fail>
                                    <html>
                                        <b>Patient ID is null, value must be present</b>
                                    </html>
                                </fail>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </validation>
                </element>
                <element id="element1" name="EncounterId" display="Encounter ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="false" value="144">
                    <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/FOCUSED_READMISSIONS_ID" />
                    <validation>
                        <rules>
                            <rule id="r0" test="#element0.value == ''">
                                <fail>
                                    <html>
                                        <b>Patient ID is null, value must be present</b>
                                    </html>
                                </fail>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </validation>
                </element>
            </elements>
        </template>
    </templates>
</dataTemplateSpecification>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<element>PatientId: 207</element>
<element>EncounterId: 144</element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath predicate is not doing what you think it does. The `*` is a selector for all child elements, not a string wildcard pattern. I assume that you rather want something like that (all `element` elements that have both a `name` and a `value` attribute):

```
//element[@name and @value]
```

And for printing out the attribute values, you might want to look into `xsl:value-of` instead of `xsl:copy` and `xsl:apply-templates` unless you want to actually copy the element.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name='newline'><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="//elements">
  <xsl:for-each select="//element[@name]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@value,$newline)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this wasn't that bad at all.  For a first XSLT I couldn't have asked for much easier.  what I wrote earlier would almost work.  But For this I would need to write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="//dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template/elements/element">   
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of>: <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This seemed to work rather well.

Comment: DMainEvent: Not too bad for a start. Here are some observations: 1. Always use the short form of `<xsl:value-of>`. Write: `<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>` and *not* `<xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of>`. 2: A template match pattern specifies a *relative* XPath expression (very rarely consisting of more than one location steps). In your case it could be just: `<xsl:template match="element">` 3. You can use a single XPath expression (and thus a single `<xsl:value-of>`) to specify a concatenation of more than one strings: just use the `concat()` function.